# Heatmap plot how to cluster variables graphically

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I have a data frame of categorical variables in case form, made up of three variables (i.e. color, shape and size). An example of the data frame is this:

```
Color    Shape     Size   Freq
1 Yellow  Square    Big    10
2 Yellow  Square    Medium  6
3 Yellow  Square    Small   3
4 Yellow  Triangle  Big     4
5 Yellow  Triangle  Medium  6
6 Yellow  Triangle  Small   8
7 Red     Square    Big     2
8 Red     Square    Medium  6
9 Red     Square    Small   5
10Red     Triangle  Big    12
.......
```

I've created a heatmap using this code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df_max <- df %>%
  group_by(Color, Shape) %>%
  slice(which.max(Freq))

head(df_max)
# Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
# Groups: Color, Shape [4]
# 
#    Color    Shape   Size  Freq
#    (chr)    (chr)  (chr) (int)
# 1    Red   Square Medium     6
# 2    Red Triangle    Big    12
# 3 Yellow   Square    Big    10
# 4 Yellow Triangle  Small     8

ggplot(df_max, aes(x = Color, y = Shape, fill = Size)) +
  geom_tile()
```

With this result:

[image]

However, the heatmap is not clear enough, and for the sake of clarity I'd need to group the colors as much as possible. For example, red colors (Size) grouping to appear closer than others colors. I've tried to arrange the data frame by size before slicing with no satisfactory result, so could anyone provide any idea on how to arrange the variables to get the final result?

Comment: I cannot provide any advice with using **ggplot2**, but maybe you can check [the example in the **ComplexHeamtap** package](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/ComplexHeatmap/inst/doc/s2.single_heatmap.html#toc_3) (the 9th heatmap if you drag down) which demonstrate how to cluster a character matrix.

Comment: @Zuguang Gu thanks for the tip. I've gone trough your document, and the package seems to work well with numeric or character matrix, but how about a contingency table like the one above? I don't see how could I use  CompleHeatmap, should I need to convert the data frame to a matrix

Comment: yes, the input is a matrix, but you can use `acast` from **reshape2** package to convert a data frame to a matrix.